# Ping between two vm in kvm

Tags: networking, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I have configured a net with one host ( my computer) and two virtual machines. I don't want to use libvirt now to connect vm to host, so i manually created bridge and two tap interfaces. Here is the configuration:

vm1 /etc/network/interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s2
iface enp0s2 inet static
address 192.168.50.3
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
up ip route add default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp0s2
```

the same for another one vm2:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp0s2
iface enp0s2 inet static
address 192.168.50.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
up ip route add default via 192.168.50.1 dev enp0s2
```

this is host :

```
auto enp4s0
 13 iface enp4s0 inet manual
 12 
 11 auto br0
 10 iface br0 inet static
  9         address 192.168.50.1
  8         netmask 255.255.255.0
  7         network 192.168.50.0
  6         broadcast 192.168.50.255
  5 #        gateway 192.168.50.1
  4         bridge_ports enp4s0 tap0 tap1
  3         bridge_stp off
  2         bridge_fd 0
  1         bridge_maxwait 0
45          dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

Host can ping vm and vms can ping host now. But from 192.168.50.3 vm 192.168.50.2 is unreachable. What is the problem here? I have read in "mastering kvm virtualization", that this is enough for getting the connection (ip forwarding is enabled, but this does not matter for bridge, as I understood)